# local module file in electron can not access node module at build

Tags: mongodb, electron, electron-builder

I have an Electron project with Nuxt.

In main.js, I'm importing a mongo.js file with :

```
var mongo = isDev() ? require("./assets/mongo.js") : require("../assets/mongo.js") ;
```

My mongo.js file is :

```
var { MongoClient } = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports = {
    // SOME FUNCTIONS
}
```

In dev, I can run and get access to functions.

During build, I got an error :

```
Cannot find module 'mongodb'
```

To include my mongo file, I had to add extraRessources to package.json :

```
"build":
    ...
    "extraResources": [
      "assets/**"
    ],
    ...
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue. I guess that, as mongo.js is considered as an extraResources it does not have access to the node_modules ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that some of you will face this issue. Here is the trick that resolve the issue.

In mongo.js file, add a mongoClient variable and set a value to it in main.js.

main.js :

```
var { MongoClient } = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongo = isDev() ? require("./assets/mongo.js") : require("../assets/mongo.js") ;
mongo.mongoClient = MongoClient
```

in mongo.js :

```
var { MongoClient } = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

module.exports = {
    mongoClient: null,

    func1() {
         // connect to mongoDB using this.mongoClient
    }
}
```